# Setting different code styles for separate projects in Pycharm

Tags: python, coding-style, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm, and it's a great editor, but I have this issue while working on a number of projects at the same time. Unfortunately, the different projects I'm working on have different code styles.
The easiest example is that one uses spaces, while another uses tabs.
While I don't want to go into the whole [Tabs vs Spaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsoOG6ZeyUI) debate, I'm wondering if there is a way to set Pycharm to use separate coding style rules per projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm's `Code Style` configuration has built-in scheme setting just for your requirement.

`Preference -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python`

After setting the style, you can store it with the project, by clicking the `Scheme` pull-down menu list. Also you can store/export the style by clicking the gear icon next to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [halfelf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43886957/3045171), I found this option:

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python
```

In the scheme options, there is a drop down list where you can choose `project` and set the choices to the relevant project only (the one that is currently chosen.

[image]

Hope this helps..